# Labelling points on a geom_point() based on the equation of geom_abline()

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, label, line

I have a fun problem for you today. Any help would be amazing.

I have geom_plot()

```
set.seed(1)
list1 <- sample(10, 100, replace = T)
list2 <- sample(7, 100, replace = T)

df <- data.frame(list1, list2)
df

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=list1, y=list2)) + geom_point()

x3 <- c(10,6)
y3 <- c(1,7)

slope3 <- diff(y3)/diff(x3)

intercept3 <- y3[1] - slope*x3[1]

ggplot(data = df, aes(x=list1, y=list2)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_abline(data = NULL, intercept = intercept3, slope = slope3, col="red")
```

What I would ideally like to do is label all the points that lay on, or to the right of the geom_abline()  I have plotted I wanted to use the geom_label_repel() function to make this look tidy, but when I tried this it just labelled every poitn! If possible, I would also like to further subset the data points on or to the right of the plotted geom_abline() in the future based on other criteria.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
set.seed(1)
list1 <- sample(10, 100, replace = T)
list2 <- sample(7, 100, replace = T)

df <- data.frame(list1, list2)
df

ggplot(data=df, aes(x=list1, y=list2)) + geom_point()

x3 <- c(10,6)
y3 <- c(1,7)

slope3 <- diff(y3)/diff(x3)

intercept3 <- y3[1] - slope3*x3[1]

#Mutate
df$prod <- intercept3+slope3*df$list1
df$label <- ifelse(df$list2>df$prod,'text',NA)

ggplot(data = df, aes(x=list1, y=list2,label=label)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_abline(data = NULL, intercept = intercept3, slope = slope3, col="red")+
  geom_text(vjust=-0.5)
```

[image]